# Delegate retention circle although using weak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, delegates

I am working with Coordinators.
My ViewController is not deallocating even though I set weak delegates.

Coordinator:

```
class JournalDetailCoordinator: Coordinator {
    var dependencys: AppDependency
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    var collectionViewController: CollectionViewWithMenuController!
    var imagePickerManager: ImagePickerManager!




    init(dependencys: AppDependency, navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.dependencys = dependencys
        self.navigationController = navigationController

    }

    func start() {
        loadCollectionViewController()
    }

    deinit {
        print("JournalDetailCoordinator deinitialisiert")

    }

    func loadCollectionViewController() {
        var journalDetailViewControllerContainer = [JournalDetailViewController]()
        for journal in dependencys.journals {
            let vc: JournalDetailViewController = dependencys.getJournalDetailDependency().createVC()
            vc.entryJournal = journal
            vc.delegateLoadImagePickerManager = self
            journalDetailViewControllerContainer.append(vc)
        }
        collectionViewController = dependencys.getCollectionViewWithMenuDependency().createVC()
        collectionViewController.managedViewControllers = journalDetailViewControllerContainer
        navigationController.pushViewController(collectionViewController, animated: true)
    }



}

extension JournalDetailCoordinator: LoadImagePickerManager {
    func loadImagePickerManager<T>(vc: T) where T : UIViewController & ImageGetterDelegate {
        imagePickerManager = ImagePickerManager()
        imagePickerManager.delegate = vc
        imagePickerManager.pickImage(viewController: collectionViewController)

    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class JournalDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var mainView: JournalDetailViewP = {
        let view = JournalDetailViewP()
        return view
    }()

    typealias myType = SetJournal & HasImagePickerManager
    // dependency
    var dep: myType!
    var entryJournal: Journaling!



    var tableViewDataSource: JournalDetailTVDataSource?
    var collectionViewInteraction: AddImageCollectionViewInteraction?

    weak var delegateLoadImagePickerManager: LoadImagePickerManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Detail Journal"
        // only for testing without coordinator connection
        //        if entryJournal == nil {
        //            entryJournal = NewJournal()
        //        }
        //        dep = AppDependency()
        setMainView()
        loadTableView()
        loadCollectionView()

    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("view did disappear Journal Detail")
    }

    deinit {
        dep.setJournal(newJournal: entryJournal)
        print("JournalDetailViewController deinitialisiert")
    }


    @objc func getImage() {
        delegateLoadImagePickerManager?.loadImagePickerManager(vc: self)
        //        dep.imagePickerManager.delegate = self
        //        dep.imagePickerManager.pickImage(viewController: self)

    }

    func saveEntry() {

    }

}

extension JournalDetailViewController: Storyboarded {}
extension JournalDetailViewController: DependencyInjectionVC {}
extension JournalDetailViewController: SetMainView {}

extension JournalDetailViewController: ImageGetterDelegate {
    func returnImage(image: UIImage) {
        if entryJournal.image[0] ==  nil {
            entryJournal.image[0] = image
        } else {
            entryJournal.image.append(image)
        }

        loadCollectionView()
    }
}

extension JournalDetailViewController: AddImageCollectionViewInteractionDelegate {
    func deleteImage(index: Int) {
    }

    func addImage() {
        getImage()
    }
}
```

They are deallocation if I do not execute the getImage() function, so I think that is the reason of the retention circle.

Thats the ImagePickerManager:

```
protocol ImageGetterDelegate: class {
    func returnImage(image: UIImage)
}

class ImagePickerManager: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    weak var delegate: ImageGetterDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("ImagePickerManager initialisiert")
    }


    deinit {
        print("imagePickerManager deinitialisiert")
    }
    /// use to pick the Image, make sure to use the root ViewController to pass in to
    func pickImage<T:UIViewController>(viewController: T) {
        let alertList = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Load Picture", comment: "Picture alert Alertcontroller"), message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) {
            UIAlertAction in self.openCamera(viewController: viewController)
            alertList.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default) {
            UIAlertAction in self.openGallery(viewController: viewController)
            alertList.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            alertList.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        alertList.addAction(cameraAction)
        alertList.addAction(galleryAction)
        alertList.addAction(cancelAction)

        viewController.present(alertList, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func openCamera<T:UIViewController>(viewController: T) {

        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let warningAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You do not have a camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .cancel) {
                UIAlertAction in
                warningAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            warningAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
            viewController.present(warningAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    private func openGallery<T:UIViewController>(viewController: T) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            print("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
            return
        }
        delegate?.returnImage(image: image)

    }

}
```

ImagePickerManager is not allocating after the Coordinator is deallocated. So I think the Retention circle is because I pass the ViewVontroller back through to the Coordinator in LoadImagePickerManager and then set the vc to the Coordinator? Does anybody have an idea how to solve that problem or what to do?

Edit:
LoadImagePickerManager:

```
protocol LoadImagePickerManager: class {
    func loadImagePickerManager<T: UIViewController & ImageGetterDelegate>(vc: T)
}
```

I think the memory leak happens here when passing the collectionViewController:

```
imagePickerManager.pickImage(viewController: collectionViewController)
```

Because I did some tests if I do not execute this part then everything is deallocating fine.

Updated ImagePickerManager class:

```
class ImagePickerManager: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    weak var delegate: ImageGetterDelegate?
    var viewController: UIViewController!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("ImagePickerManager initialisiert")
    }


    deinit {
        print("imagePickerManager deinitialisiert")
    }
    /// use to pick the Image, make sure to use the root ViewController to pass in to
    func pickImage<T:UIViewController>(viewController: T) {
        self.viewController = viewController
        let alertList = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Load Picture", comment: "Picture alert Alertcontroller"), message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) {
            UIAlertAction in self.openCamera()
            alertList.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default) {
            UIAlertAction in self.openGallery()
            alertList.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            alertList.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        alertList.addAction(cameraAction)
        alertList.addAction(galleryAction)
        alertList.addAction(cancelAction)

        viewController.present(alertList, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func openCamera() {

        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let warningAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You do not have a camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .cancel) {
                UIAlertAction in
                warningAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            warningAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
            viewController.present(warningAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    private func openGallery() {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            print("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
            return
        }
        viewController = nil
        delegate?.returnImage(image: image)

    }

}
```

I added a viewController variable to the class, and set it through the pickImage() and then when the image is selected I set the variable to nil. Then the UIViewController gets deallocated, but still the class ImagePickerManager stays alive and does not get allocated.

Comment: You should revise your question to post as little code as possible. Right now it feels like wall of code.

Comment: Thanks, okay I will update the question. The problem is i dont know exactly where the problem is..

Comment: I think you can shorten your sample code with a minimalistic example that reproduces the issue and is a reflection of your code as well. That way, more people will be able to understand your issue, and help you. :)

Comment: Check `AddImageCollectionViewInteractionDelegate` is weak or not at its data source object.

Comment: yes all the delegates are weak

Comment: yes I will try to do this as soon as I am back on my laptop. I already deleted a lot of code out. But I tried to leave the stuff in there that deals with the delegates

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using weak delegate so, in no way it is going to create a retain cycle.

I think your viewController is not deallocating because your viewController is still in the stack of your navigation.

Try to remove all the viewControllers from the navigation stack and then your deallocate block will work as usual.

Try the following code depending upon your requirement(present/push) when you are coming back to your homeViewController:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Edit:**

Make sure your protocol is a class type then only weak reference will work.

```
protocol LoadImagePickerManager: class {

}
```

In your PickerManager try to dismiss using following code, it will redirect you to rootview controller, but you can again push or present to the required viewcontroller:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But why does the viewController deallocate if the getImage() is not executed?

Comment: I updated my code, yes my protocol is a class type. I also did some more tests and I found out that I think the memory leak happens when passing the CollectionViewController to the ImagePickerManager and using it for the AlertController.

Comment: so I think the problem is in ImagePickerManager, I added a variable viewController to the ImagePickerManager and set it nil after the Image is selected then the ViewControllers are deallocating. But ImagePickerManager itself still does not deallocate so there is something wrong in this class I posted the updated ImagePickerManager class. Thanks for your help